# SQL Subquery returned more than 1 value, without update it works fine

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

This query works and returns 260 rows:

```
SELECT PRODUCTS.ProductResalePrice * ((100 - isnull((select discountperc from CUSTOMERDISCOUNT where CustomerID = CUSTOMERS.CustomerID and CategoryID = products.CategoryID), 0)) / 100) AS incDisc
FROM  PRODUCTS
INNER JOIN SHIPMENTPRODUCTS op ON PRODUCTS.ProductID = op.ProductID
INNER JOIN SHIPMENTS ON op.shipmentid = shipments.shipmentid
INNER JOIN CUSTOMERS ON shipments.CustomerID = CUSTOMERS.CustomerID
left JOIN CUSTOMERDISCOUNT ON CUSTOMERS.CustomerID = CUSTOMERDISCOUNT.CustomerID
    AND PRODUCTS.CategoryID = CUSTOMERDISCOUNT.CategoryID
WHERE op.shipmentid = 1234
```

This is also 260 rows:

```
select * from SHIPMENTPRODUCTS where shipmentid = 1234
```

but the next one gives:

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

```
update SHIPMENTPRODUCTS set SoldFor = 
    (SELECT PRODUCTS.ProductResalePrice * ((100 - isnull((select discountperc from CUSTOMERDISCOUNT where CustomerID = CUSTOMERS.CustomerID and CategoryID = products.CategoryID), 0)) / 100) AS incDisc
         FROM  PRODUCTS
         INNER JOIN SHIPMENTPRODUCTS op ON PRODUCTS.ProductID = op.ProductID
         INNER JOIN SHIPMENTS ON op.shipmentid = shipments.shipmentid
         INNER JOIN CUSTOMERS ON shipments.CustomerID = CUSTOMERS.CustomerID
         left JOIN CUSTOMERDISCOUNT ON CUSTOMERS.CustomerID = CUSTOMERDISCOUNT.CustomerID
              AND PRODUCTS.CategoryID = CUSTOMERDISCOUNT.CategoryID
         WHERE op.ProductID = SHIPMENTPRODUCTS.productid and op.shipmentid = SHIPMENTPRODUCTS.shipmentid)
where SHIPMENTPRODUCTS.shipmentid = @shipmentId
```

and I seriously have no clue. Also have no idea how to start this. The difference is only that query 1 is standalone and query 2 is query 1 wrapped in an update statement.

Comment: Query1 returns more then one row, so the update can't be done. You want to add 260 rows into SHIPMENTPRODUCTS table?

Comment: In the inner query add op.ShipmentId= @shipmentId also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are trying to do:

```
update SHIPMENTPRODUCTS
set SoldFor = PRODUCTS.ProductResalePrice * ((100 - isnull((select discountperc from CUSTOMERDISCOUNT where CustomerID = CUSTOMERS.CustomerID and CategoryID = products.CategoryID), 0)) / 100)
FROM PRODUCTS
INNER JOIN SHIPMENTPRODUCTS op ON PRODUCTS.ProductID = op.ProductID
INNER JOIN SHIPMENTS ON op.shipmentid = shipments.shipmentid
INNER JOIN CUSTOMERS ON shipments.CustomerID = CUSTOMERS.CustomerID
left JOIN CUSTOMERDISCOUNT ON CUSTOMERS.CustomerID = CUSTOMERDISCOUNT.CustomerID
     AND PRODUCTS.CategoryID = CUSTOMERDISCOUNT.CategoryID
WHERE op.ProductID = SHIPMENTPRODUCTS.productid and op.shipmentid = SHIPMENTPRODUCTS.shipmentid)
where SHIPMENTPRODUCTS.shipmentid = @shipmentId
```

Comment: that's it indeed. don't know why I made a subquery lol! have to wait 9 minutes before I can accept this answer according to SO